# iOS Xcode Can't find Edge Inset

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, storyboard, interface-builder

I'm trying to learn from this tutorial: "[Auto Layout Tutorial in iOS 9 Part 1: Getting Started](https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2)" on `RayWederlich`
I'm following the same setup: `IOS 9` and `Xcode 7`

He has this step: "Each view is inset 20 points from the window’s borders; the padding between the views is also 20 points."

I can't for the life of me find where to set those for a `UIView` in storyboard? Is it only done by Code? Is it a mistake done during the conversion of the article from `IOS 7` to `IOS 9`?

Comment: They are just telling you to drag the views out and line them up similar to the picture. Then they tell you the frames so you can match them exactly. You can enter those values in the size inspector which is the ruler tab of the right-hand pane. They are demonstrating the difference between the old way springs and struts and the new way auto layout.

Comment: Not sure why you accepted that answer. Your question had nothing to do with settings constraints. And they told you the exact wrong thing to do for that part of the tutorial.

Comment: after his answer, I found that I needed a tutorial on the new stuff, the anchors (not the layout constraints), which involves what the answer said, so I ditched that tutorial all together because of that and also because its use of old interface builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thin you want this:
[image]

the tutorial have old Interface Builder graphics.

For make 20 point:

[image]